# How to access a site on AWS EC2 without a domain name

Tags: iis, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I just created a new site on my IIS on Amazon's EC2 and I was wondering if there is a way to access it publicly without assigning a domain.

In detail. I created a new site dev.example.com which is accessible when I am logged in my instance. Is there a way to access it outside by doing let's say 54.xxx.xx.xxx:80:dev.example.com

I don't know if that's even possible so any hints are appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely do this, but here's what you'll need to do:

- Make sure IIS is configured to route any incoming connection on a particular IP address to your site.   This is distinct from IIS specifically listening for a particular hostname (e.g. mywebsite.com).
- As an alternative to the above, you could also manually set your DNS on your local computer and then use your web browser to visit mywebsite.com.  From IIS's perspective, a user will have requested mywebsite.com just as if public DNS were set
- As far as the IP address you visit, your instance will either have an ephemeral Public IP Address which will be reset when the instance is stopped and started, or an Elastic IP Address, which persists across restarts.
- As @Anthony Manzo mentioned, you'll need to make sure that your Security Group associated with this instance allows Port 80.  In addition, you may want to disable Windows Firewall completely (or check that it allows Port 80 on all three "Zones" (Windows Firewall has 3 different zones to manage).

Answer (score 2):

Afaik the IP addresses assigned to EC2 instances can change throughout its lifetime and therefore you should instead generate an Elastic IP Address (which will always direct to your instance). That way, you don't have to deal with DNS yourself and still are always able to connect to your instance.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the "Security Groups" on the left hand of your EC2 web console.  You'll have to allow TCP 80 (and whatever else) in the Security Group (probably 'default') first.

Comment: all necessary stuff under security groups are done. I can see the default site for IIS and stuff when I check the IP address but then  how do i check the new site...?